# Why does a Windows program not work for a certain user, but it works for other users?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I installed [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) on my parents' computer running Windows 10. I extracted the zip file, renamed `exiftool(-k).exe` to `exiftool.exe`, then moved `exiftool.exe` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ExifTool`. Then I updated the System PATH environment variable to include `c:\Program Files (x86)\ExifTool`.

When I run exiftool from the command line using my administrator account (in a non-admin cmd.exe), it works fine:

```
C:\Users\me>exiftool -ver
12.76

C:\Users\me>
```

When I run exiftool from the command line using my dad's non-administrator account, it works fine:

```
C:\Users\dad>exiftool -ver
12.76

C:\Users\dad>
```

But when I run exiftool from the command line using my mom's non-administrator account, it does not work at all:

```
C:\Users\mom>exiftool -ver

C:\Users\mom>exiftool

c:\Users\mom>
```

Just typing `exiftool` by itself should have printed out a ton of usage information, but it printed nothing. Typing `path` from my mom's command line, I can see that `c:\Program Files (x86)\ExifTool` is in the PATH. It would have printed out an error anyway if it was a PATH problem.

The fact that exiftool runs fine for my admin account and my dad's non-admin account would indicate that this is a problem with my mom's Windows account, not an exiftool problem. But I set up my mom's account the same way I set up my dad's account, so I'm not sure why my mom's account can't run exiftool.

Comment: Just in case, run the tool by specifying its full absolute path plus its extension (`"c:\Program Files (x86)\ExifTool\exiftool.exe" -ver`?). What is the result?

Comment: The result is the same - nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your post indicates a damaged User Account (as you have noted). There is no practical way to fix a damaged or broken Windows User Profile.

There are numerous reasons why an account goes bad.

Two ways to fix it:

(1) Back up everything, install Windows fresh and recover all your data. This is probably best and easiest.

(2) Replace the damaged use profile. This is more picky but it can be done.

To make a new User Profile.

> (a) Log in as yourself. Make a good copy in a secure (non-User)
> location and back up all documents, data and email, and also favorites
> if you have many favorites.
>
> (b) Assuming this current but damaged User is a member of
> Administrators, make a new Windows User Account and make it a member
> of Administrators.
>
> (c) Log in as the new administrator account. Go to Advanced System
> settings and make a copy of the damaged profile. Locate the profile
> backup in the same folder as you established for your data.
>
> (d) Now I assume you want the new User to have the same name as the
> damaged one. So then you now need to delete the damaged profile. Be
> certain you have all your backups.
>
> (e) Delete the user id of the damaged profile and then make a new user
> with the same name. Make this a member of Administrators.
>
> (f) Log in as the new user, and set it up. Most apps will need to be
> run under the new user.
>
> You may wish to thoroughly review the steps a couple of times.
>
> Once you are ready, start in and create the new User and Profile.

There are several resources for doing this, and the one below is very close.

[Replace damaged user account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile-in-windows-1cf41c18-7ce3-12f9-8e1d-95896661c5c9)

Comment: I have shown you two ways to fix this.   @pacoverflow